# Spock mock method implementation not working when checking invocations number

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I have a problem with mocking methods using Spock. Below is the code which I am using. Without any change everything is working - mock implementation work properly and returns "mock" string. However if I uncomment line with invocation check (3 * notifier.test()) my mock implementation for method **notify** is not invoking and tests fails because notifier mock returns null. Why it works like that?

```
class Aaaaa extends Specification {
    class Notifier {
        def test() {
            println("Called in impl...")
            return "impl"
        }
    }

    def "Should verify notify was called"() {
        given:
        Notifier notifier = Mock(Notifier)
        notifier.test() >> {
            println("Called in mock...")
            return "mock"
        }

        when:
        notifier.test()
        notifier.test()
        def result = notifier.test()

        then:
//        3 * notifier.test()
        result == "mock"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Mockito-style splitting of stubbing and mocking into two separate
>   statements will not work

From docs: 
http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing

It is required to define number of invocation in the same line where mock method is defined

Answer (score 2):

To post an actual answer for those who follow:

```
    def "Should verify notify was called"() {
        given:
        Notifier notifier = Mock(Notifier)

        when:
        notifier.test()
        notifier.test()
        def result = notifier.test()

        then:
        3 * notifier.test() >> {
            println("Called in mock...")
            return "mock"
        }
        result == "mock"
    }
```